# TypeORM and postgress deadlock

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have this code which outputs an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore.

**Caller**

```
const res = await getManager().transaction(async entityManager => {
    return ServiceA.method1(entityManager);
});
```

**Service A**

```
static async method1(entityManager: EntityManager) {
    const deleteResult = await entityManager //changing this line to getManager() fixes the issue, but in other situations it still comes back
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .setLock('pessimistic_write')
        .delete()
        .from(MyEntity)
        .where('relate = :id', { id: some id })
        .execute();

    await ServiceB.method1({
        ...
        entityManager: entityManager
    });

    await ServiceB.method2({
        ...
        entityManager: entityManager
    });
    return true;
}
```

**Service B**

```
static async method1(params: {
    ...
    entityManager: EntityManager;
}) {
    let lockedEntityOne = await EntityOneDao.getAndLock(..., params.entityManager);
    if (!lockedEntityOne) throw new Error('not found');

    //modify lockedEntityOne

    const aNewRelatedEntityOne = await this._createANewRelatedEntityOne()
    await params.entityManager.save([lockedEntityOne, aNewRelatedEntityOne]);
    return lockedEntityOne;
}

static async method2(params: {
    ...
    entityManager: EntityManager;
}) {
    let lockedEntityTwo = await EntityTwoDao.getAndLock(..., params.entityManager);
    if (!lockedEntityTwo) throw new Error('not found');

    //modify lockedEntityTwo

    const aNewRelatedEntityTwo = await this._createANewRelatedEntityTwo()
    await params.entityManager.save([lockedEntityTwo, aNewRelatedEntityTwo]); //where the above error is thrown
    return lockedEntityTwo;
}
```

In the `Service A` if i change the line which uses a passed in `entityManager` with the import `getManager()` from 'typeorm' package, then the particular case is fixed. However in other situations it comes back. I know this is a lot, but I'm wondering if passing `entityManager` around to sort of reuse it is a bad idea. All help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I've removed all "pessimistic_write" locks from entities, but problem persists. I still don't understand why using a fresh manager resolves this particular case and fails with same error in other cases.